# Mosquitto Broker - DNS name instead of IP address for MQTT clients to use

Tags: kubernetes, mqtt, mosquitto, coredns

I am able to get eclipse mosquitto broker up and running with the MQTT clients able to talk to the broker using Broker's IP address. However, as am running these on kubernetes, the broker IP keeps changing on restart. I would like to enable DNS name service for the broker, so the clients can use broker-name instead of the IP. coreDNS is running default in kubernetes..

Any suggestions on what can be done ?

```
$ nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:     10.43.0.10
Address:    10.43.0.10:53

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried. The nslookup command is trying to look up a domain not a host which is not going to work.

Comment: Currently, I was trying to see how to get a pod.name ping working in kubernetes, so that I can use the same string in the MQTT client. But that also didnt work for me as below : 

kubectl get pods
mqtt-broker              1/1     Running            0          9d

[#] ping mqtt-broker.mosquitto-broker
ping: mqtt-broker.mosquitto-broker: Name or service not known
[#]

 kind: Pod
 metadata:
   name: mqtt-broker

Comment: [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65960042/edit) the question to add details

Comment: i don't think you understand how K8s DNS works...  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: I had problem like your question how to setup Mosquitto listener DNS IP broker ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services). You create it by setting the clusterIP field in a service spec to None. Once you do that the DNS server will return the pod IPs instead of the single service and instead of returning a single DNS A record, the DNS server will return multiple A records for the service each pointing to the IP of an individual pod backing the service at the moment.

With this your client can perform a single DNS A record lookup to fetch the IP of all the pods that are part of the service. Headless service is also often used as service discovery system.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: your-headless-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None # <-- This makes the service hadless! 
  selector:
    app: your-mosquito-broker-pod
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
```

You are able also to resolve the dns name with regular service as well. The difference is that with headless service you are able to talk to the pod directly instead having service as load-balancer or proxy.

Resolving the service thru dns is easy and you do that with the following pattern:

```
backend-broker.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Whereas `backend-broker` corresponds to the service name, `default` stands for the namespace the service is defined in, and `svc.cluster.local` is a configurable cluster domain suffix used in all cluster local service names.

Note that if you client and broker are in the same namespace you can omit the `svc.cluster.local` suffix and the namespace. You then reffer the servie as:

```
backend-broker
```

I high encourage you to read more about [Dns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services) in kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

All,

Thanks for answering the query, especially Thomas for code pointers. With your suggestions, once I create a Service for the POD, I was able to get the DNS working as core-dns was already running .. I was able to use the hostname in MQTT broker also after this.

```
    opts.AddBroker(fmt.Sprintf("tcp://mqtt-broker:1883"))

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-02-01T19:08:46Z"
  labels:
    app: ipc
  name: mqtt-broker
  namespace: default
```

BTW, I wasnt able to get the headless service working, was getting this error, so continued with ClusterIP itself + 1883 exposed port for MQTT. Any suggestions please ?

```
`services "mqtt-broker" was not valid:`
`spec.clusterIPs[0]: Invalid value: []string{"None"}: may not change once set`
```